# Issue using bind variables in PL\SQL script

Tags: plsql

I am trying use bind variables in an oracle procedure and I am running into an error.  Below is the code I am using:

```
DECLARE
sql_stmt        varchar2(4000);
parm1           varchar2(100);
parm2           varchar2(100);
parm3           varchar2(100);
parm4           varchar2(100);

BEGIN
parm1   := 'test1';
parm2   := 'test2';
parm3   := 'test3';
parm4   := 'test4';

sql_stmt :=  ‘EXEC PROCESS_ARCHIVE.START_PROCESSARCHIVE(CHR(39)||:1||CHR(39),null, CHR(39)||:2||CHR(39), CHR(39)||:3||CHR(39), CHR(39)||:4||CHR(39))’;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using parm1,parm2,parm3,parm4;

END;
/
```

When this executes, I get the error: "SP-0552:Bind variable "4" not declared".  I am a beginner to PL\SQL so I am still learning but I cannot figure out where this error is coming from.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't know if that could help, but why are the quotes of string so strange (not just the apostrophe sign) and why do you include `EXEC` statement inside that string? And after all, if you want to call a simple procedure like that, you totally don't need to use Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me...

```
create or replace procedure testProc(a varchar2,
                                     b varchar2 default null,
                                     c varchar2,
                                     d varchar2,
                                     e varchar2) as
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('a: '||a);
    dbms_output.put_line('b: '||b);
    dbms_output.put_line('c: '||c);
    dbms_output.put_line('d: '||d);
    dbms_output.put_line('e: '||e);
end;
/

declare
    sql_stmt varchar2(4000);
    parm1 varchar2(100);
    parm2 varchar2(100);
    parm3 varchar2(100);
    parm4 varchar2(100);
begin
    parm1 := 'test1';
    parm2 := 'test2';
    parm3 := 'test3';
    parm4 := 'test4';

    sql_stmt :=  'begin testProc(:1, null, :2, :3, :4); end;';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using IN parm1, IN parm2, IN parm3, IN parm4;
end;
/
```

Results in...

```
a: test1
b:
c: test2
d: test3
e: test4
```